# How to fix unhandled exception access violation

Tags: c, pointers

I have written a logic to find out common elements from two arrays. But the program breaks at the if condition giving an exception saying Access violation reading location 0x00000002.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void intersect(int[2][2],int[2][2],int,int);
int main()
{
    int arr1[2][2]={{2,5},{6,8}};
    int arr2[2][2]={{1,2},{8,8}};
row = (sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]));
     col = (sizeof(arr1[0])/sizeof(arr1[0][1]));
intersect(arr1,arr2,row,col);
}

void intersect(int **ptr1, int **ptr2,int row, int col)
{
    int i = 0, j= 0, x = 0, y = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <row ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < col ; j++)
        {
                for(x = 0; x < row ; x++)
                {
                    for(y = 0; y < col ; y++)
                    {
                        if(ptr1[i][j] == ptr2[x][y]) 
                            printf("%d\t",ptr1[i][j]);

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it says in detail: First-chance exception at 0x002b1572 in Array.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002. Unhandled exception at 0x002b1572 in Array.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002.

Comment: what are `row` and `col` in `main`?

Comment: Also `int **` is not a 2D array.

Comment: surprised you don't get warnings about conflicting declarations for `intersect` since you have 2 definitions for it

Comment: @ChristianGibbons its the row and column of array

Comment: Ron, you never declare them.

Comment: @xing It gives error [col] parameter is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ptrN` as double pointers, you can tell the array size like:

```
void intersect(size_t row, size_t col, int a1[][col], int a2[][col])
{
    size_t i = 0, j= 0, x = 0, y = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <row ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < col ; j++)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < row ; x++)
            {
                for(y = 0; y < col ; y++)
                {
                    if(a1[i][j] == a2[x][y]) 
                        printf("%d\t",a1[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int a1[][col] col is not allowed as a parameter.

Comment: @RonAxm - what do you mean by not allowed?

Comment: @RonAxm - When doing `ptr[x][y]` the number of columns must be known to calculate the correct address. There you can't use `int** ptr`

Comment: sir it is giving me an error that parameter col is not allowed in the subscript [col].

Comment: @RonAxm - Are you sure you fixed it for both places ? See https://ideone.com/q7TStn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158885/discussion-between-ron-axm-and-4386427).

Answer (score 0):

when you are passing `2D array` as a argument to function, you should catch with `pointer to an array` not with double pointer because 2D array and double pointer are not same..

```
    #define r 2
    #define c 2


    void intersect(int (*ptr1)[r], int (*ptr2)[c],int row, int col)
    {
           //function body
    }
```

Comment: what is 2?I don't want to pass default values Is there no other way ?

Comment: @RonAxm I edited my answer. You can use macro because macro are replaced at preprocessor stage itself.

Answer (score 0):

This works... not sure if it's what you wanted.

```
void intersect(int** ptr1, int** ptr2, size_t row, size_t col)
{
int i = 0, j = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {
                int a = *(int*)((DWORD)ptr1 + (i * (col * sizeof(int))) + (j * sizeof(int)));
                int b = *(int*)((DWORD)ptr2 + (x * (col * sizeof(int))) + (y * sizeof(int)));

                if (a == b)
                    printf("%d\t", a);
            }
         }
      }
    } 
 }
```